# base property in IndexColumn annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Anybody know what does it mean base property in @IndexColumn annotation?
And what a different between base=0 and base=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from [IndexColumn API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/IndexColumn.html) base property is index in DB start from base which default to 0.

It means what is the starting point in your database for indexing. Java arrays are 0-based, but in database you might have 1..n values, where `base` would be 1 then. eg.:

```
@IndexColumn(base = 1)               @IndexColumn(base = 0)

DB     Java                          DB     Java
1      0      <---  position  -->    0      0
2      1                             1      1
3      2                             2      2
```